# How and when should I use _POSIX_C_SOURCE in C programs?

Tags: c, compilation, posix, multiplatform, building

I've gotten myself into having to maintain some C project which should also compile on older platforms. At the moment, for some platforms, the macro `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is defined. I was wondering - if it's acceptable to have it defined, should I not just define it always, on all platforms? And perhaps with the highest relevant value?

To generalize, I suppose I'm asking: When and under what conditions should `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` be used?

Answer (score 6):

`_POSIX_C_SOURCE` makes different functionality available.

`_POSIX_C_SOURCE 1` makes the functionality from the POSIX.1 standard available.
`_POSIX_C_SOURCE 2` makes the functionality from the POSIX.2 standard available.
`_POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L` makes the functionality from the POSIX.1b standard available.

Higher values like 200809L make more features available. (man 7 feature_test_macros)

In general `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is needed if you need [strict POSIX compliance](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html#tag_02_02_01).

It is safe to define it in every project if you don't care for specific POSIX standard compliance.

Comment: What do you mean by "not caring for specific POSIX standard compliance"? Isn't it the other way around, i.e. _enforcing_ specific POSIX standard compliance?