# _POSIX_ vs _POSIX_SOURCE vs _POSIX_C_SOURCE

Tags: c, posix

<sub>(split this off from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48460942/1593077))</sub>

The following 3 macros appear in many C source files which try to detect/rely on the availability of [POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1780599/1593077) functionality:

- `_POSIX_SOURCE`
- `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`
- `_POSIX_` (and `_POSIX` ?)

In the linked-to question it's explained that we're supposed to set `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to the POSIX version on which we want to rely (although setting it doesn't guarantee that the functionality will actually *be* available - that's up to the compiler/OS). Also, while I can set it as the *user*, it's not clear when *others* set it themselves (e.g. the compiler / build system). For the other two, I know neither when I should set them nor when others set them.

So, what is the difference in meaning between the three macros? When would each of them be set for me? And why/when should I choose to set one of them over the others, if at all?

Comment: It's a lot to go through, but [here is the official POSIX reference online](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). The *Base Definitions* chapter, section 2 (Conformance) contains the definition for `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`. You can also use the reference to search for specific functions and see what macros they might need.

Answer (score 2):

Very partial answer (and with thanks to @SomeProgrammerDude):

---

The [POSIX reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) tells us that:

> The POSIX.1-1990 standard specified a macro called _POSIX_SOURCE. This has been superseded by _POSIX_C_SOURCE.

and in practical terms, the GNU C library manual [tells](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) us, for example:

> The state of _POSIX_SOURCE is irrelevant if you define the macro _POSIX_C_SOURCE to a positive integer.

and it should probably be the same for other C standard library implementations. So - never use `_POSIX_SOURCE` yourself, only use `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` (except if you are on old platforms where the OS and libraries have not seen updates for the past 20 years at least).

---

`_POSIX_` and `_POSIX` is a Microsoft-Visual-C(++)-specific macro. I am **guessing** you define it to get MSVC to expose POSIX/POSIX-like functionality. According to [this non-authoritative thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/33014416/) on the MinGW mailing list, MSVC no longer uses `_POSIX_` (and `_POSIX`?) as of MSVC2013.